# Backup Exchange Mailboxes in powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Is there a way to do this without receiving all the error of non mailbox accounts as well...

I am finding in order to backup mailboxes of disabled user account in AD I need to do the following:

```
$baseou = "OU=Companies,DC=triangle,DC=com"
$MyDisabledUsers = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $baseou -AccountDisabled | select name
$MyListOfDisabledUsersThatHaveMailboxes = foreach ($mbx in $MyDisabledUsers) {Get-Mailbox  $mbx.name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
foreach ($AllMailboxes in $MyListOfDisabledUsersThatHaveMailboxes) { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $AllMailboxes -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($AllMailboxes.Database)-$($AllMailboxes.DisplayName)-$($AllMailboxes.Alias).pst" }
```

However, even though it works I am receiving a bunch of errors for each disabled user account that does not have a mailbox.

> WARNING: The cmdlet extension agent with the index 0 has thrown an exception in OnComplete(). The exception is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current sta te of the object.    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ExchangePrincipal.get_ServerFullyQualifiedDomainName()
>   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.Initialize(MapiStore
>   linkedStore, LogonType logonType, ExchangePrincipal owner,
>   DelegateLogonUser delegateUser, Object identity, OpenMailb
>   oxSessionFlags flags, GenericIdentity auxiliaryIdentity)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__10(MailboxSession
>   mailboxSession)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.InternalCreateMailboxSession(LogonType
>   logonType, ExchangePrincipal owner, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String
>   clientInfoString, IAccountingOb ject budget, Action`1
>   initializeMailboxSession, InitializeMailboxSessionFailure
>   initializeMailboxSessionFailure)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.CreateMailboxSession(LogonType
>   logonType, ExchangePrincipal owner, DelegateLogonUser delegateUser,
>   Object identity, OpenMailboxSessionFlag s flags, CultureInfo
>   cultureInfo, String clientInfoString, PropertyDefinition[]
>   mailboxProperties, IList`1 foldersToInit, GenericIdentity
>   auxiliaryIdentity, IAccountingObject budget)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.ConfigurableOpen(ExchangePrincipal
>   mailbox, MailboxAccessInfo accessInfo, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String
>   clientInfoString, LogonType logo nType, PropertyDefinition[]
>   mailboxProperties, InitializationFlags initFlags, IList`1
>   foldersToInit, IAccountingObject budget)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.OpenAsSystemService(ExchangePrincipal
>   mailboxOwner, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String clientInfoString)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.MailboxLoggerFactory.XsoMailer.Log(AdminLogMessageData
>   data, LogMessageDelegate logMessage)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.AdminLogProvisioningHandler.OnComplete(Boolean
>   succeeded, Exception e)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Provisioning.ProvisioningLayer.OnComplete(Task
>   task, Boolean succeeded, Exception exception)

It works but I would really like to not have the error show.

In the past others have been told to use the following command:

```
foreach ($AllMailboxes in (Get-Mailbox -Filter {(ExchangeUserAccountControl -eq 'AccountDisabled' -and ResourceType -ne 'Room' -and SamAccountName -notlike 'TDRK_*' -and DisplayName -notlike 'Discovery*')})) { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $AllMailboxes -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($AllMailboxes.Database)-$($AllMailboxes.DisplayName)-$($AllMailboxes.Alias).pst" }
```

Though this works, it does not export all disabled user accounts that have mailboxes. only exchange disabled mailboxes which is different.

Any Suggestions.

Comment: At first glance it is odd you even get an error since you should only be processing ones that have a mailbox associated to them. The errors from that are suppressed by `-erroraction silentlycontinue`. Which command is throwing the error?

Comment: Also `$allmailboxes` is a _very_ misleading variable name considering how you are using it.

Comment: Agreed that is why I am asking to see what I can do to improve the above code to no receive the error. I thought I covered it when I suppressed the errors. But have failed.

Comment: in the above code:

'$baseou = "OU=Companies,DC=triangle,DC=com"
$MyDisabledUsers = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $baseou -AccountDisabled | select name
$MyListOfDisabledUsersThatHaveMailboxes = foreach ($mbx in $MyDisabledUsers) {Get-Mailbox  $mbx.name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
foreach ($Mailboxes in $MyListOfDisabledUsersThatHaveMailboxes) { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailboxes -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailboxes.Database)-$($Mailboxes.DisplayName)-$($Mailboxes.Alias).pst" }'

Comment: In the above code:

foreach ($Mailboxes in $MyListOfDisabledUsersThatHaveMailboxes) { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Mailboxes -FilePath "\\it-fs02\pst$\$($Mailboxes.Database)-$($Mailboxes.DisplayName)-$($Mailboxes.Ali‌​as).pst" }

Comment: How do you add the code blocks like you did.

Comment: What is your version of exchange?

Comment: The can happen with 2010 pre rollup 7. Some people use this to surpress the errors at an org level. : `Set-AdminAuditLogConfig -AdminAuditLogEnabled $False`